# Embedding Controllers in Twig including dependency injection in parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony 6.3 with Twig. I have a nav partial templates in which I would like to send some datas from a Repository Class. I saw in the Symfony documentation that embedding a Controller in a template is possible.

So :

1. I made a controller which render my nav template sending the datas I need

   ```
   class BookController extends AbstractController
   {
       public function listForNav(BookRepository $bookRepository): Response
       {
           $books = $bookRepository->findFiveMostRecent();

           return $this->render('partials/_nav.html.twig', [
               'books' => $books
           ]);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I made a loop in my Twig template to get my books and display the titles in ma nav bar

   ```
   {% for book in books %}
       <a href="{{ path('book_show', {'id': book.id}) }}">
           {{ book.title }}
       </a>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
3. I included the "render" "controller" functions in my base.html.twig where I want to include my nav bar template

   ```
   {{ render(controller(
           'App\\Controller\\BookController::listForNav', {$bookRepository}
       )) }}
   ```
4. I also change my framework config as it is mentionned in the documentation

   ```
   framework:
       fragments: { path: /_nav }
   ```

I have an error saying my variable in

```
{{ render(controller(
        'App\\Controller\\BookController::listForNav', {$bookRepository}
    )) }}
```

parameters doesn't exists ($bookRepository).

I'm a little confused and not really used to TWIG. Maybe it doesnt recognize dependency injection, the documentation doesn't mentionned it.

If somebody can help it would be very much appreciated. THX in advance

Comment: Twig only knows about variables that you pass when you first do the rendering.  It has no idea about $bookRepository which presumably is just a doctrine repository.  Make sure you have `listForNav(BookRepository $bookRepository)` and then just remove $bookRepo from your twig.

Comment: 1) should already autoinject the repository. no need to give it.
The modern solution for this would be a twig component for the whole nav. see https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-twig-component/current/index.html

Comment: Thanks both of you. It worked by only removing the injection in the render / controller function